# Handsontable - numeric columns type

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

Why when i set column type to `numeric` , table can't sorting in righ way.
It is doing it like that:

[image]

What format i need to set?

**EDIT**

**Problem solved.**

I had string in my dataset. When i parse to float now its working.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. I see no such behaviour when I try to reproduce it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m66r31am/).

Comment: That's because your data is string and not number, so "159" comes before "59" (same as "APPLE" comes before "POCKET").

Comment: Oh, I see you've solved the problem. Good!
Can you put your answer as an answer so that the question-answer is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had my data as string. After parse it to float/integer it's working.

> @kumar_harsh That's because your data is string and not number, so
>   "159" comes before "59" (same as "APPLE" comes before "POCKET").